# Tomcat server port access

Tags: tomcat, router, fortigate

I have changed the tomcat default port to `8091` (eg. `http://localhost:8091/project`) which has been set up in intranet server and is working very fine within the network.I have to provide access to the application (only to port `8091`) to some users outside the network or some IPs in the network.what could be the solution ?

**Note** : I had provided access to specific ports(`8091` including `8005`,`8009`,`8443`,`8444`,`80`,`8080`) from router to the outside network users but its not working. But same thing is working for IIS server like ports `8082`,`8084` assigned for IIS is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tomcat `server.xml` configuration file and ensure that you have not configured it to listen only on localhost (127.0.0.1) i.e. look for an entry `address=""` in your connector definition and remove it. This explains why it works in the same host when you access it with  `http://localhost:8091/project`